# Remove file extention from urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some urls in my website like this..

```
http://www.mydomain.com/about.php
http://www.mydomain.com/contact.php
http://www.mydomain.com/signup.php
http://www.mydomain.com/testimonials.php ...... and much more
```

Now I am trying to convert above urls to user friendly url

```
http://www.mydomain.com/about
http://www.mydomain.com/contact
http://www.mydomain.com/signup
http://www.mydomain.com/testimonials
```

This is code in my .htaccess file that I am tried so far. But it doesn't work.

```
# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

Anyone can help me to remove .php etension from my urls?? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the conditions you are using and instead use the below 2 lines in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule   ^whatever/?$   whatever.php  [NC]
```

This will work even if user types a forward slash after the name or not

If you want to make them dynamic, [**here's**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) a good tutorial on that

Comment: I already use this first line 'RewriteEngine On' in my .htaccess file

Comment: @TNK use the second line, change whatever to your desired name and other with page name

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it changing your second line something like this `RewriteRule   ^about/?$   about.php  [NC]` but nothing change in my original url

Comment: @TNK because your href must be having that value, you type this in your url and see `http://www.mydomain.com/about/`, you need to replace links like `<a href="http://www.domain.com/about/">`

Comment: Mr. Alien tell me do I need to remove the “.php” from my href links?

Comment: can I know is there any other solution to do same without removing .php from href links?

Comment: @TNK Yes you need to, I've provided a link for the tutorial, you can go through it, but I assume my solution works?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30204/discussion-between-tnk-and-mr-alien)

Answer (score 0):

for a proper implementation so as not cause confusion during deployment if you dont have access to the htaccess file of your server or if it is override. You can consider a library like toro-php http://toroweb.org/ for easy routing.